# Created dummy using get_dummies. Concatenation of dummy dataframe to original dataframe df causes rows to vanish

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dummy = pd.get_dummies(df['sub_grade'],drop_first=True)
df.drop(labels='sub_grade',axis=1, inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df,dummy],axis=1).head()
```

Note: df has 396030 rows. 
The categorical column name is 'sub_grade'. In the first line I converted it to numerical columns using get_dummies. 
In the second line I dropped the sub_grade column all together from df. 
The third line concatenates df with my dummy dataframe. When this line is executed the total rows in df becomes 5.

Comment: `df.head()` displays only the first few rows of a data frame.

Comment: But even when I do df.info(), it shows only 5 rows in my df

Comment: Try: df.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True)

Comment: Removing the head() from the third line of code solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the head() from the third line of code solved the problem.